# How to control image sizes inside of table

Tags: org-mode, org-table, images

I know that you can write something like:

```
#+attr_html: :width 250 px
[[./linl/to/image.jpg]]
```

But what if I have them inside of a table like:

```
| [[./linl/to/image.jpg]] | [[./linl/to/image2.jpg]] |
```

Alternatively, is there another way to visualize images side by side in org mode?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are happy with just HTML export and that all the images in the table should have the same width, you can use CSS:

```
#+HTML_HEAD:  <style> td img {width: 250px;} </style>
```

It's a blunt instrument but if you don't ask too much of it, it can work.
If you are trying to tweak each image differently, I think the best you can do is edit the HTML file to change:

```html
<td class="org-left"><img src="./img/image1.jpg" alt="image1.jpg" /></td>
```

to

```html
<td class="org-left"><img src="./img/image1.jpg" alt="image1.jpg" width="250px" /></td>
```

I don't know of a way to add a distinguishing id to each image so you can target your CSS to each image and tweak it.

I don't know of a generic way to deal with side-by-side images in all backends (other than the table method you are using).